# Talend Samba components fail when disabling SMBv1

Tags: talend, samba, smb, cifs

I'm using the following Talend Exchange components in Talend v6.3.1 to interact with a Windows shared directory (from a Linux server):
* tSambaPut
* tSambaGet
* tSambaList
* tSambaFileProperties
* tSambaDelete
* tSambaWaitForFile

SMBv2 and v3 are on the Windows server, but when v1 is disabled the Samba components cannot communicate with the server.  We need to remove v1 and have a large number of jobs we'd like to avoid refactoring.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

> SmbException: the remote file cannot be found!
>   Exception in component tSambaPut_1
>   java.lang.Exception: SmbException: the remote file cannot be found!
>       at edhproduct_611.testsamba_0_1.TestSamba.tSambaPut_1Process(TestSamba.java:2385)
>       at edhproduct_611.testsamba_0_1.TestSamba.tFixedFlowInput_2Process(TestSamba.java:2156)
>   ...

Indicated line numbers do not map properly to the generated code.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more information about the failure like stack traces, logs, error messages. Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Comment: Detail added.  
I also notice that this component makes use of the following: jcifs-1.3.11.jar

Comment: The solution I've settled on is to replace these components with refactored versions that use the hierynomus/smbj library.  By using the same component names I will be able to avoid touching these jobs, and only need to republish and deploy them.